# UIImage not updating on Unwind Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

In my ViewController I have an empty UIImageVIew that I am hoping to populate with an image.

The user taps a button, a modal view pops up and the user draws an image.

Then the user taps 'Done' which fires an unwind segue back to my view controller.

In that unwind segue function I am attempting to update the UIImage to no avail.

I am definitely getting an image back through though, I just don't think its updating the UIImageView.

This is the Unwind Segue function in my main view controller:

```
@IBAction func saveImage(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

    println("Should be able to save here right?")
    if(segue.sourceViewController .isKindOfClass(CustomerFairProcessingSignatureViewController))
    {
        var view2:ModalViewController = segue.sourceViewController as! ModalViewController



        if view2.imageView.image != nil{


          //img is an IBOutlet  
        img.image = view2.imageView.image

        }else{


        println("Theres no image brah")
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing the "image setting" on the main thread? All UI changes must be performed on the main thread.

Try using this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

   img.image = view2.imageView.image

})
```

Instead of this:

```
img.image = view2.imageView.image
```

Comment: thanks for the response, i tried this, it didn't make any difference. It's all done on the main thread anyway I think.